# TruePlay interface

Tags: c++, uwp, visual-studio-2017, anti-cheat

I tried to run TruePlay tutorial from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt808781(v=vs.85).aspx , but got an error :

> "Unable to activate Windows Store app 'AppName'. The ProcessName
>   process started, but the activation request failed with error
>   'ErrorNumber'(it says "an error has been found in the system binary file, try to restore your PC)- translation from russian "

I used a new C++ UWP project in Visual Studio 2017

Also, when i change my Package.appxmanifest (like in tutorial from link above) and build the project this warning comes out:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gflN.png

*File manifest:*

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Package
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
  xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
  xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
  xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">


  <Identity
    Name="76f3b46c-58e3-422b-a2ee-c9d7dfd62e9b"
    Publisher="CN=dana"
    Version="1.0.0.0" />

  <mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="76f3b46c-58e3-422b-a2ee-c9d7dfd62e9b" PhonePublisherId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"/>

  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>App6</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>dana</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>Assets\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>

  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
  </Dependencies>

  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate"/>
  </Resources>

  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App"
      Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe"
      EntryPoint="App6.App">
      <uap:VisualElements
        DisplayName="App6"
        Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png"
        Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png"
        Description="App6"
        BackgroundColor="transparent">
        <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png"/>
        <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
      </uap:VisualElements>
    </Application>
  </Applications>

  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="gameMonitor" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="protectedApp" />
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

Comment: Can you answer the question from the closed (duplicate) question?

Comment: I've answered. Maybe notification didn't come. Here is a copy-paste from closed question:  
I changed TargetDeviceFamily like you said.Target platform version and Target platform min version- 10.0.16299.0 the result remained the same – Данил Спирин 2 days ago

Comment: I can reproduce the issue... checking...

Comment: Are you working with a Microsoft account rep for your game? You can't use this feature, even for side - loading, without permission from Microsoft.

Comment: No, i didn't get this permission. How can i reseive it?

Comment: I'm doing a research work which is related with anti-cheat technologies in university, if it's matter.